# Python Beautifulsoup - problem read <span>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to extract "brand-logo", "product-name", "price" and "best-price  " from the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="catalog-wrapper">
    <div class="slideout-filters"></div>
    <section class="catalog-top-banner"></section>
    <section class="search-results">
    <section class="catalog">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
        <div class="catalog-container">
          <a class="catalog-product catalog-item ">
            <div class="product-image "></div>
            <div class="product-description">
              <div>
                <div class="brand-logo">
                  <span>PACO RABANNE</span>
                </div>
                <span class="product-name">
                    PACO RABANNE PERFUME MUJER 30 ML
                </span>
                <span class="price">Normal: S/ 219</span>
                <span class="best-price  ">Internet: S/ 209</span>
```

"brand-logo" and "product-name, done, but I can not read "price" & "best-price  " 
I tried it this way:

```
box_3 = soup.find('div','col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9')   
    for div in box_3.find_all('div','product-description'):
    d={}
    d["Marca"] = div.find_all("div",{"class","brand-logo"})[0].getText()    
    d["Producto"] = div.find_all("span",{"class","product-name"})[0].getText()    
    d["Precio"] = div.find_all('span',class_='price')    
    d["Oferta"] = div.find_all('span',class_='best-price  ')    
    l.append(d)
    l
```

out:

```
{'Marca': 'PACO RABANNE',
'Oferta': [],
 'Precio': [<span class="price">Normal: S/ 219</span>],
 'Producto': 'PACO RABANNE PERFUME MUJER 30 ML'}
```

**can anyone help me?**

Answer (score 2):

You can find the `"product-description"` `div` and then iterate over the desired `div` classes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
_to_find = ['brand-logo', 'product-name', 'price', 'best-price']
s = soup(content, 'html.parser').find('div', {'class':'product-description'})
final_results = [(lambda x: s.find('span', {'class':i}).text if not x else x.text)(s.find('div', {'class':i})) \
    for i in _to_find] 
filtered = [re.sub('^[\n\s]+|[\n\s]+$', '', i) for i in final_results]
```

Output:

```
['PACO RABANNE', 'PACO RABANNE PERFUME MUJER 30 ML', 'Normal: S/ 219', 'Internet: S/ 209']
```

Comment: Thanks, but this message appears to me. 
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.
  This message appeared to me in other solutions that I tried.
  any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, without the actual website I'm unable to check the solution :(.

Maybe you should extract data from "not working" part the same way as the working one (this is lucky guess - without website or just website that will be parsed by bs4, I'm really unable to test it).

```
d["Precio"] = div.find_all('span',{"class","price"})[0].getText()    
d["Oferta"] = div.find_all('span',{"class","best-price"})[0].getText()
```

It might be good idea to make new method/function that will get the chosen attribute and handle potential errors.

Comment: I had already tried this option, but it did not work. returns the following message: 
  IndexError: list index out of range.
the page is: https://simple.ripley.com.pe/belleza-y-accesorios/perfumeria/todos-los-perfumes